# Why are these different numbers the same?

Tags: java, floating-accuracy

I'm doing unit testing and I've got this line:

```
assertEquals(1.1886027926838422606868849265505866347, 1.18860279268384230000000000000000000000,0);
```

With a delta of 0 they should have to be exactly the same in order to pass and they are clearly not, however this test passes, try it yourself.

Changing the delta to 1E-50 still passes.

Why is it passing when they are two very different numbers?

Comment: Probably because Java doesn't support numbers that big.

Comment: @luoluo how is this similar to that question?

Answer (score 10):

This is because Java compiler rounds these two numeric literals to the same number.

Run this experiment:

```
System.out.println(1.1886027926838422606868849265505866347);
System.out.println(1.18860279268384230000000000000000000000);
```

This prints the same number ([demo](http://ideone.com/mnc4fS)):

```
1.1886027926838423
1.1886027926838423
```

The `double` primitive type can only handle up to 16 decimal places, so it cannot represent these numbers all the way to the last digit.

If you want full precision, use [`BigDecimal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) instead.

Comment: You say 16 decimal places, so if I multiply everything by 10^16 can I have another 16 decimal places?

Comment: @Aequitas No. The (roughly) 16 decimal places is a limitation of the language. The number has to be rounded. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

Comment: @Aequitas Not exactly: the number of correct digits you get would stay the same, but it would get re-distributed among the whole and the fractional part ([demo](http://ideone.com/xMpHdp)).

Comment: so it's 16 SF not DP ?

Comment: @ThePcLuddite To be more accurate, it's a limitation of the [IEEE 754 double-precision binary floating-point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) standard that most CPU's and programming languages use to store `double` values (for languages that support `double`).

Answer (score 0):

The difference between the two numbers is too small to represent, so they compare as equal. You get roughly 16 decimal digits of precision.